# MYSQL: can foreign key contain a collection?

Tags: mysql

I want do a foreign key in a one table that will points on a collection of other values.

For example I want do a parent table, and a child table. while each parent should contain **all** his children, and each children should contain his parent.

So my question is can I do this in MySQL? How can I do this if yes, and what can I use otherwise;

Comment: If you're using any flavor of relational DBMS (SQL), you need to reformulate your requirement for collections, parents, and children in the language of entities and relationships.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model  Then it will be much easier to create tables to go with your entities and fks to define your relationships.

Comment: Edit your question and provide an example using data.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, ykaner. Would you mind drawing some sort of ASCII art diagram that shows us what data you're dealing with?

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is just a foreign key relationship:

```
create table children as (
    childId int auto_increment primary key,
    parentId int not null,
    . . .
    constraint fk_children_parent foreign key (parentId) references parents(parentId)
);
```

This fulfills your two requiremens:

- each parent should contain all its children
- each child should contain its parent

If you want the children for a parent, you do:

```
select parentId, group_concat(childId) as children
from children
group by parentId;
```

Answer (score 0):

A Foreign Key defines a **column (or a collection of columns)** that enforces a relationship between two Tables. It is the responsibility of the database server to enforce this relationship to ensure accurate data. The model definition of a Foreign Key consists of a parent (primary) Table containing a unique set of data that is then referred to in a child (foreign) Table.

For complete explanation have a look at this :http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/database_engineering/foreignkeys.html